# Svelte reactivity not triggering when variable changed in a function

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I am a bit confused here and unluckily I couldn't get any solution on the discord channel of svelte so here I go...

I have a rather basic example of two classes, let them be `App` and `Comp`.
`App` creates a `Comp` instance and then updates this instance's `value` after a button click.

The Comp instance should set this value to a different variable (`inputValue`) and upon changing that variable it should fire `validate(inputValue)` which is reactive. Here is a REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/1df2eb0e67b240e9b1449e52fb26eb14?version=3.25.1

App.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Comp from './Comp.svelte';
    
    let value = 'now: ' + Date.now();
    
    function clickHandler(e) {
        value = 'now ' + Date.now();
    }
</script>

<Comp
    bind:value={value}
/>
<button type="button" on:click={clickHandler}>change value</button>
```

Comp.svelte:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let value;

    let rendered = false;
    let inputValue = '';

    $: validate(inputValue); // This doesn't execute. Why?

    function validate(val) {
        console.log('validation:', val); 
    }

    onMount(() => {
        rendered = true;
    });

    $: if (rendered) {
        updateInputValue(value);
    }

    function updateInputValue(val) {
        console.log('updateInputValue called!');
        if (!value) {
            inputValue = '';
        }
        else {
            inputValue = value;
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={inputValue}>
```

So as soon as the value is changed:

1. The reactive `if (rendered) {...}` condition is called
2. `updateInputValue` is called and `inputValue` is changed. HTML input element is updated to this value.
3. `validate(inputValue)` never reacts to this change - **WHY?**

If I omit the extra call to the `updateInputValue` function in the reactive `if (rendered)` condition and put `updateInputValue` function body's code directly to the condition, then `validate(inputValue)` is triggered correctly, i.e.:

```
// works like this  
$: if (rendered) {
    if (!value) {
        inputValue = '';
    }
    else {
        inputValue = value;
    }
}
```

So how come it doesn't work when updated in the function?

Comment: Notice that it's working if you write something in the input manually (without clicking the button).

Comment: @johannchopin That I find logical & correct because of the direct binding to `inputValue`, i.e. it excludes calling the reactive `if` statement and thus `updateInputValue` function. But I need to be able to update the value from outside of the component => changing the `value` prop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@johannchopin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63934944/1513547) has revealed the issue.

---

You can read [my blogpost for slightly in-depth explanation of how reactive declaration works](https://lihautan.com/compile-svelte-in-your-head-part-2/#reactive-declaration), here's the tl;dr:

- reactive declarations are executed **in batch**.

  svelte batches all the changes to update them in the next update cycle, and before it updates the DOM, it will execute the reactive declarations to update the reactive variables.
- reactive declarations are executed **in order** of their dependency.

  reactive declarations are executed in batch, and each declaration is executed once. some declarations are depending on each other, eg:

  ```js
  let count = 0;
  $: double = count * 2;
  $: quadruple = double * 2;
  ```

  in this case, `quadruple` depends on `double`. so regardless of order of your reactive declarations, `$: double = count * 2;` before `$: quadruple = double * 2` or the other way round, the former should be and **will be** executed before the latter.

  Svelte **will sort** the declarations in the dependency order.

  In cases where there's no dependency relationship with each other:

  ```js
  $: validate(inputValue);
  $: if (rendered) updateInputValue(value);
  ```

  1st statement depends on `validate` and `inputValue`, 2nd statement depends on `rendered`, `updateInputValue` and `value`, the declaration is left in the order as it is.

---

Now, knowing this 2 behaviors of reactive declaration, let's take a look at your [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1df2eb0e67b240e9b1449e52fb26eb14).

As you change `inputValue`, `rendered` or `value`, Svelte will batch the changes, and start a new update cycle.

Right before updating the DOM, Svelte will execute all the reactive declaration in 1 go.

Because there's no dependency between the `validate(inputValue);` and `if (rendered) updateInputValue(value);` statements, (as explained earlier), they will be executed in order.

If you change `rendered` or `value` only, the 1st statement (`validate(inputValue)`) will not be executed, and similarly, if you change `inputValue` the 2nd statement (`if (rendered) updateInputValue(value)`) will not be executed.

Now, in the `updateInputValue` you change the value of `inputValue`, but because we are already in an update cycle, we wont start a new one.

This usually isn't a problem, because if we sort reactive declarations in dependency order, the statement that updates the variable depended on will be executed before the statement that relies on the variable.

---

So, knowing what's wrong, there's a few "solutions" you can go for.

1. Manually reorder the reactive declaration statements, especially when there's an implicit dependency of the order of execution.

See the difference of ordering the reactive declaration in this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ccaf261cad864282916c48135d3e8eaf?version=3.25.1)

So change your REPL to:

```js
$: if (rendered) {
  updateInputValue(value);
}
$: validate(inputValue);
```

[See REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4a8ca26e254743979783caf0af0d988a?version=3.25.1)

2. Explicitly defining the dependency in the reactive declarations

```js
$: validate(inputValue);

$: if (rendered) {
    inputValue = updateInputValue(value);
}
    
function updateInputValue(val) {
    console.log('updateInputValue called!');
    if (!value) {
        return '';
    }
    else {
        return value;
    }
}
```

[See REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4a8ca26e254743979783caf0af0d988a?version=3.25.1)

Comment: Great answer ;) Thanks again for it.

Answer (score 6):

Really strange (and I couldn't really explain it) but if you put the reactive statement `$: validate(inputValue);` after the function `updateInputValue` declaration, it's working as expected:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    export let value;
    
    let rendered = false;
    let inputValue = '';

    function validate(val) {
        console.log('validation:', val);
    }
    
    onMount(() => {
      rendered = true;
   });
    
    $: if (rendered) {
        updateInputValue(value);
    }
    
    function updateInputValue(val) {
        console.log('updateInputValue called!');
        if (!value) {
            inputValue = '';
        }
        else {
            inputValue = value;
        }
    }
    
    $: validate(inputValue);
</script>
```

Check this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4dce7d79a41d4251960257bc1b2feb33?version=3.25.1).

Comment: That's an excellent catch, I didn't think of that. Thanks! This looks like a bug to me... Please take an upvote meanwhile.

Comment: @Fygo Yeah it's really curious could you open an issue on the repo?

Comment: If you look at compiled js, you will notice that reactivity is obtained via marking a variable ’dirty’. If you have the `validate()`-function call before assigning a value to `inputValue` variable, then `inputValue` is not dirty and therefore `validate()` is not called. (To notify also @johannchopin)

Comment: Problem seems to be that the assignment to `inputValue` doesn’t mark it dirty and this happens if the `inputValue` assignment is in subfunction. This works fine `$: if (rendered) { inputValue=updateInputValue(value);  }` and this also works `$: if (rendered) { inputValue=’’;updateInputValue(value);}` In first version you must of course return the correct value from function. I believe this is a bug.

Comment: Yeah you're right but since I didn't read something about it in the official documentation it could be helpful to open an issue for that. Have you the time for it @grohjy?

Comment: @johannchopin I created a semi-report/semi-question yesterday about this, which got closed unluckily, but I guess it could be reopened. If you are interested, here is the link: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5408

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example of original post’s problem and couple of workarounds:

```
<script>
  let nb
  let n=0
$: console.log("nb1:",nb)
$: update(n)
$: console.log("nb2:",nb)
function update(v) {
  console.log("update",v)
  nb = v
}
</script>
<h1 on:click={()=>n=Math.floor(Math.random()*100)}>click: {nb}</h1>
<h1 on:click={()=>update(Math.floor(Math.random()*100))}>click: {nb}</h1>
```

The first log of `nb` is not fired when `n` is assigned a new value and `$: update(n)` runs due to assignment. The second log of `nb` is run, because it’s after the assignment to `nb`.
If `update`-function is called directly (last `h1`) everything works.

If you assign a value to `nb` at top level everything works also:

```
 <script>
      let nb
      let n=0
    $: console.log("nb1:",nb)
    $: nb = update(n)
    $: console.log("nb2:",nb)
    function update(v) {
      console.log("update",v)
      return v
    }
    </script>
    <h1 on:click={()=>n=Math.floor(Math.random()*100)}>click: {nb}</h1>
    <h1 on:click={()=>update(Math.floor(Math.random()*100))}>click: {nb}</h1>
```

I believe this a bug.