# Reactive declarations seems not work? Or am I using the 'hooks' the wrong way?

Tags: svelte

I am writing a SPA Svelte app with `svelte-navigator`. I want to fetch a request when `pathname` is changed.

```js
import { useLocation } from "svelte-navigator";
import { useCallApi } from "./hook";

const loc = useLocation();
const [resp, fetchPageData] = useCallApi(); // my `hooks` to call api

$: pathname = $loc.pathname;
$: loading = $resp.loading;
$: data = $resp.data;

$: {
  console.log("loading changed", loading);
}

$: if (pathname) {
  console.log(pathname);
  fetchPageData(); // when pathname change, call a api
}
```

`fetchPageData` is called when `pathname` changed everytime, but the reactive declarations(`$: loading`) does not update everytime.

My way to use `hooks` looks like this:

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export function useCallApi() {
    let result = writable({
        loading: false,
        data: 0,
    });

    const fakeFetch = async () => {
        result.update(pre => ({
            data: 0,
            loading: true,
        }));
        
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
        
        result.update(pre => ({
            data: Math.random(),
            loading: false,
        }));
    };

    return [result, fakeFetch];
}
```

The online demo is https://svelte.dev/repl/e367c0aa3c9743cb8a749f92f0239d59?version=3.32.1 .

When click `To a` or `To b` to change the `pathname`, reactive declarations update only once.

But when click the button `trigger request`, all state update likes what I expected.

I want to know what is wrong with this, `svelte`, `svelte-navigator` or `my hooks`? And why?

I would be most grateful if you could help me out.

---

updated: 2021-02-02

My friend found that the `statements order` affects the update behavior, which looks somewhat like the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63977760/12153710). If put `fetchPageData()` to the top, the update behavior looks good.

```js
import { useLocation } from "svelte-navigator";
import { useCallApi } from "./hook";

const loc = useLocation();
const [resp, fetchPageData] = useCallApi();

//  the order is important which will affect the update behavior
$: if (pathname) {
  console.log(pathname);
  fetchPageData();
}

$: pathname = $loc.pathname;
$: loading = $resp.loading;
$: data = $resp.data;

$: {
  console.log("loading changed", loading, $resp.loading);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why but when you replace the auto-subscription `$` by `resp.subscribe()` it works :

```js
import { useLocation } from "svelte-navigator";
import { useCallApi } from "./hook";

const loc = useLocation();
const [resp, fetchPageData] = useCallApi(); // my `hooks` to call api

$: pathname = $loc.pathname;

let loading;
let data;
    
resp.subscribe( result => {
    loading = result.loading;
    data = result.data;
});

$: {
  console.log("loading changed", loading);
}

$: if (pathname) {
  console.log(pathname);
  fetchPageData(); // when pathname change, call a api
}
```

You could try it here : https://svelte.dev/repl/ca065fdc188e41938b8e3db0b8c61f20?version=3.32.1

I think the answer is behind the way svelte executes reactive statements.

According to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63977760/12153710 :

> svelte batches all the changes to update them in the next update cycle, and before it updates the DOM, it will execute the reactive declarations to update the reactive variables.

When you update your router from a , I think that compiled code waits the promise to resolve (in `hook.js`) before updating the reactive statement `$: loading = $resp.loading;` and `$: data = $resp.data;` and therefore the `{ loading }` and `{ data }` for the DOM.

Comment: My friend found that  the `statements order` affects the update behavior, which looks somewhat like the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63977760/12153710). If put `fetchPageData()` to the top, the update behavior looks good. But I still fell confused....o(╥﹏╥)o